# Libgdx Scene2d buttons like in Minecraft

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I'm trying to make a ui where the user can select what item to use, something similar to minecraft but I'm not sure what kind of widget is used on that game. What I did is make a few buttons and add them to a table so that they would be aligned. But the problem with buttons is that there is no way of knowing if an item is selected, because after it is clicked it just go to it's original look.

```
btnCube = new TextButton("Cube", btnStyle);

        btnCube.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                WorldController.element = "cube";
                super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);
            }
        });
```

for me I just set a string to a certain text, then when a player click on the screen it spawns that object, is there a better way of doing it? because I think it is not proper to just rely on a string to select items.

[image]

This is what I was talking about, as you can see the red item is highlighted because it is selected and the rest is not.

Comment: Use ChangeListener instead of ClickListener. Use a button style with a checked Drawable for when the button is toggled.

Comment: I did what you said but the problem now is how to auto disable a button when another button is clicked, instead of clicking in to enable and click again to disable. What should I put inside the changeListener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give all of your buttons the same change listener. It calls its `changed` method when a button is toggled. However, since you don't want the buttons to be able to toggle from on to off by clicking them, you should manually apply the change to all buttons. So first put the whole group of buttons into a Set.

Then when `changed` is called, you will know which button was just pressed so you can change the state of all of them to the appropriate state.

```
private ObjectSet<Button> toolButtons = new ObjectSet(); //put all buttons into this

//add this same listener to all buttons.
ChangeListener commonListener = new ChangeListener(){
    public void changed (ChangeEvent event, Actor actor){
        for (Button button : toolButtons){
            button.setChecked(button == actor);
        }
        setSelectedTool((Button)actor);
    }
};

void setSelectedTool(Button button){
    //however you are tracking the selected tool, you can apply the change
    //here based on which button was pressed
}

//Also need to set programmatic change events false on all buttons to prevent stack overflow
for (Button button : toolButtons)
    button.setProgrammaticChangeEvents(false);
```

You seem to be using Strings to track which tool is selected. Since you are using Strings, you can conveniently name your buttons using the string value, and then use that in the `setSelectedTool` method. For example:

```
btnCube = new TextButton("Cube", btnStyle);
btnCube.setName("cube");
btnCube.addListener(commonListener);
toolButtons.add(btnCube);

//...
void setSelectedTool(Button button){
    WorldController.element = button.getName();
}
```

But Strings are not a robust way to track this. Really you should be using an Enum. If you use enums, you can store them in the Button's user object:

```
btnCube = new TextButton("Cube", btnStyle);
btnCube.setUserObject(ElementType.CUBE); //example enum you need to create
btnCube.addListener(commonListener);
toolButtons.add(btnCube);

//...
void setSelectedTool(Button button){
    WorldController.element = (ElementType)button.getUserObject();
}
```